# How to get only a part of a file with a Javascript AJAX request(no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have checked Google and answers and tutorials, I know how to get only a part of a file by AJAX using jQuery, but I could not find any instructions on how to do it with plain JS.

I have tried:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'https://website.html .my-class');
```

Does not work, lookign for an element by ID did not work either.

```
xhr.open('GET', 'https://website.html');
```

This returns the whole file.

I have not tried to cache and fragment the whole returned file, I doubt that would work anyway.

So, how is this done? Certainly it's possible, right?

Comment: Jquery gets the whole file and extracts the selected elements for you. So look into how to do that.

Comment: actually jquery parses the entire retrieved document and gives you only the specific part you mention.Here's a quote from jquery's load method :`When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container` : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Well, yeah, that is cool, but how is that done in JS, any idea where in the jQuery source code this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DOMParser()` to create an HTML `document` from `XMLHttpRequest.responseText`, then use `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve the specific selectors from `document`

```js
var file = `data:text/html,
           <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
               <body>
                 <div class="my-class">my class</div>
               </body>
             </html>`;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", file, true);
request.onload = function() {
  var html = request.responseText;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  var el = doc.querySelector(".my-class");
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}
request.send();
```

Comment: Let's not speak about if it's wrong or right to parse HTML with regex, it's wrong in most cases. Will `new DOMParser();` be faster than regex? ;)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev _"Let's not speak about if it's wrong or right to parse HTML with regex, it's wrong in most cases. Will `new DOMParser();` be faster than regex? ;)"_ That should be a Question onto itself. Actual times of the comparison can be measured to provide accurate results, without speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use jquery. Less time.
Alternatively you can use the `DOMParser` object of web API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
this parse your file text/html, then you can search for the class you want